# XML output using PHP 4 from database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xml, output

I need to get XML output file with `PHP 4` (I know that it is easier using php 5 but at this point I cannot upgrade it in our company) The data is extracted from a `MySQL` database.

Here is a code snippet I wrote but it is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html>
<body>
<?php

  // Establish db connection

  require_once ('config.php');

  $sql= "SELECT * FROM GeneralProperty
  WHERE fname= '".$_POST["fname"]."' AND target= '".$_POST["target"]."'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql)
  OR die ("Error: $sql <br>".mysql_error());

  header('Content-type: text/xml');
  header('Pragma: public');
  header('Cache-control: private');
  header('Expires: -1');
  echo '<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>';

  echo '<xml>';
  while ($row =mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      echo '<Feature>';
      echo '<featureName>' .'Feature Name (FAJ xxxx/x):'. '</featureName>';
      echo '<f>'. $row['fname'].'</f>';
      echo '</Feature>';
  }
  echo '</xml>'; 
  ?>  
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You should get an error because you sent HTML and BODY tags before the header. You might have buffering turned on to avoid that, but most people don't. So, that would be an error. Beyond that, you don't need the DOCTYPE and HTML and BODY tags. Remove them. You only need the header and XML.

Comment: You mean I need to make a php file and delete all others?  I don't understand about header and body that you mentioned. Could you give me a sample of code snippet?

Comment: Do you see the first three lines of the code you pasted above? Delete them. Do you see the last two lines of the code you pasted above? Delete them. This is XML output. Don't put that HTML in there.

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't work. it seems that the syntax for getting  data from data base and put it in this format doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? You get no output at all? You get output, but it looks wrong? It doesn't work when you open it in an XML program? It doesn't submit properly to some other service?

Comment: Actually I want to see it in the new web page open. but the page is totally empty.

Comment: If you view the source of the page and it is empty, you have a syntax error in your code. You need to check the error logs on the server to see what the error is.

Comment: PHP 4 was end-of-lifed **6 years, 7 months ago**. It is dangerously irresponsible of your company to run it in production.